# How do I change the color of a GMarker in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Pretty simple request, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do it.  I just want my GMarkers to be green instead of red.

Do I really have to make my own icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I have found is with the following scripts...

[labeledmarker.js](http://uwmike.com/maps/manhattan2/labeled_marker.js.source)

[mapiconmaker.js](http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapiconmaker/release/src/mapiconmaker.js)

you then need the following code snippet:

```
var iconOptions = {};
iconOptions.width = 32;
iconOptions.height = 32;
iconOptions.primaryColor = "#66CC6600";
iconOptions.cornerColor = "#66CC6600";
iconOptions.strokeColor = "#000000FF";
var iconSeller = MapIconMaker.createMarkerIcon(iconOptions);

function createMarker(icon, point,html,label) 
{
    opts = 
    { 
        "icon": icon,
        "labelText": label,      
        "labelClass": "markerLabel",
        "labelOffset": new GSize(-4, -31)
    };
    var marker = new LabeledMarker(point, opts);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", 
        function() 
        {
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        });
    return marker;
}
```

Make sure you have a class in your stylesheet called `markerLabel` so you can style the div which contains the label.  I pinched most of this code from the excellent [econym](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/) tutorial site where there are many clear examples and code samples.

Answer (score 4):

This is the simplest method:

```
var greenIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
greenIcon.image = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/green-dot.png";
var markerOptions = { icon:greenIcon };

var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
```

That marker image is Google's, but you could also use your own.

MapIconMaker is great if you need to generate unique markers on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Map Overlays > Markers > Icons](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/overlays.html#Icons_overview)

> **Icons**
>
> Markers may define an icon to show in
>   place of the default icon. Defining an
>   icon is complex because of the number
>   of different images that make up a
>   single icon in the Maps API. At a
>   minimum, an icon must define the
>   foreground image, the size of type
>   `GSize`, and an icon offset to
>   position the icon.
>
> The simplest icons are based on the
>   `G_DEFAULT_ICON` type. Creating an
>   icon based on this type allows you to
>   quickly change the default icon by
>   modifying only a few properties.

It looks like this is the simplest case. You use `G_DEFAULT_ICON` as the base `GIcon`, then extend it by altering the `.image` property of that new object. The [simple example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/examples/icon-simple.html) is pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I need project for add gmarker in map and getting data from web services